# Angular 16 templates are not recognizing angular/common and other modules directives

Tags: angular, phpstorm, webstorm

Can someone help me?

Here are the images:

[image]

resolved my problems

Comment: What is your IDE version? Maybe you need to upgrade it (in case if you are **not** using the latest version)

Comment: It works for me with the latest WebStorm. Please provide more information so the error is reproducible.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. My version of PhpStorm is 2022.3.1.

Answer (score 1):

[WEB-60191](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-60191/Angular-16-standard-Angular-directives-are-reported-as-not-provided-by-any-applicable-directive) is fixed in 2023.1.1, please try upgrading the IDE

Comment: Thank you, I will update my IDE and get back to you.